# Real-Time Validation of MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to do something like a "CheckList" which would update in realtime when, for instance, all required fields are entered and other field validation has passed.
Is it possible to achieve this with Knockout.Js?
Main question really is whether you can check for MVC *ModelState* and its error collection in client-side script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you look into the Knockout Validation plugin:

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

I realize you're trying to do server side validation, but the only way to do that is with an ajax request to the server - you'd have to send a request every time the values change. It may be a better approach to do some of the validation on the client, and that plugin will definitely help

Answer (score 0):

You can check the form validation like this ,

```
    if ($("#your_form_id").valid()){
      // if it is valid continue ;
    }
```

Comment: That's entirely jQuery validation - and it's fine. But if you'd like to access the server-side validation remotely, with all the annotations and stuff, there's always [remote validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)